# Not able to match multiline content in a SWIFT message (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I want to go over a SWIFT message using RegEx. I have the following excerpt from it:

```
:16R:FIN
:35B:ISIN CH0117044708
ANTEILE -DT USD- SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX FUND V - SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX EQUITY FUND USA
:16R:FIA
```

I am trying to fit the complete information in group 3:

```
ISIN CH0117044708
ANTEILE -DT USD- SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX FUND V - SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX EQUITY FUND USA
```

Instead, I am getting: `ISIN CH0117044708` only.

My RegEx doesn't work and I am trying to debug and can't find the solution. This is the RegEx expression: `/:([0-9]{2}[A-Z]){1}(::|:)((.*\r\n){1,4}|.*)/gm`

Here to play around with it:
https://regex101.com/r/qX9cET/2

**Edit:**
How would we go about matching this pattern (optional):
`([A-Z]*)(?:\/\/)?(.*(?:\/)?){0,2}`

- No // and / in line
- // and a single /
- // and two /

Included in the old one (https://regex101.com/r/Ubci69/5):

```
:16R:FIN
:97A::SAFE//0123-456789-11-020
:35B:ISIN CH0117044708
ANTEILE -DT USD- SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX FUND V - SWISSCANTO (CH)
INDEX EQUITY FUND USA
:16R:FIA
:93B::AGGR//UNIT/0,117
:19A::HOLD//CHF237,15
:92B::EXCH//JPY/CHF/0,0087535442107
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to capture in the third capturing group could be to use `[\s\S]` instead of the dot to also match whitespace characters and use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that what is on the right side does not match `:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]:{1,2}` what you try to match at the beginning.

Note that you can omit `{1}` and if you don't use the first and the second capturing group you could omit those to get your values in only the first capturing group.

`:([0-9]{2}[A-Z])(::|:)((?:[\s\S](?!:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]:))*)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLfh6l/1)

**Explanation**

- `:` Match literally
- `([0-9]{2}[A-Z])` Match in the first capturing group 2 times a digit followed by an uppercase character
- `(::|:)` Capture in the second capturing group two or one times a colon
- `(` Start third capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[\s\S]` Match any character including whitespace characters
    - `(?!:` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right does not

      - `[0-9]{2}[A-Z]:` Match in the first capturing group 2 times a digit followed by an uppercase character and a colon
    - `)` Close negative lookahead
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
- `)` Close third capturing group

**Update**: A more efficient version of the above regex using the dot. This will match the pattern with the colons at the start and then matches any character till the end of the string with an optional line break. Then it will us a negative lookahead to assert matching not the part with the colons and matches the whole line in a repeating pattern.

`:([0-9]{2}[A-Z])(::|:)(.*(?:\r?\n)?(?:(?!:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]:).*(?:\r?\n)?)*)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNw0OD/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give this a try. But one comment, the `(:{1,2})` matches only one `:`. I had it like you suggested, but it was non-greedy.

Comment: @Spurious I see what you mean, I will update the answer with the alternation.

Comment: @Spurious I have added an update with a more efficient pattern.

Comment: Really, thanks a lot! I actually wasn't aware of the negative look ahead. One comment regarding the updated pattern, is matches the last line break as well.

Comment: I've added another pattern for the `//` and `/` occurences to split them out into various groups.

Comment: @The fourth bird - very good answer !